# How to get acces to a specific array field when data read in from a csv-file

Tags: java, csv

I have a .csv-File with twitter data. There are rows and columns.

My code to read it in is:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile = "twitter.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ";";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String twitter[] = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        System.out.println(twitter[2]);

        }

    }
```

Now when i use System.out.println(twitter[2]) he will print the third column:

- lat
- 41.0338573
- 40.73792159
- 40.89123297
- 40.79269762
- 40.75165756
- 40.76348875
- 40.89118717
- 40.73816787
- 40.72321205
- 40.6832726
- 40.76314446
- 40.7263692

My question: 
How can i access one specific field in my array. I don't want the whole column printed. I just want one number of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your while loop, change it to this:

```
    int row_desired = 123;
    int row_counter = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (row_counter++ == row_desired) {
            String twitter[] = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            System.out.println(twitter[2]);
        }
    }
```

note, that will leave out your column header, add a `|| row_counter == 1` clause to the if expression evaluation to show the header

Comment: Hey, thank you very much it works! Although i dont really understand why it works. Does row_desired somehow address my array? I just see the declaration of a variable that has nothing to do with my array?!

Comment: the variable 'row_counter' is used to count each line read from the 'br.readLine()' loop start.  Then the if clause will only turn the data read into an array and output your field when that row_counter equals the 'row_desired' number.

Comment: ahhhh got it now. Clever. ;)